# Bot Framework V4 UniversalBot nodejs

Tags: node.js, botframework

What's the alternative of UniversalBot(v3) in v4. Can anybody give me a straight answer?.  I've read the documentation but i can't figure it out.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? There are a number of samples in v4 here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples

Answer (score 0):

There are comprehensive v3 to v4 migration docs in the official documentation. You don't mention any sort of context for what you're doing, so I'm going to go with a general answer:

**To create a bot instance:**

*v3*

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, [ ...DIALOG_STEPS ]);
```

*v4*

```
// Define the bot class as extending ActivityHandler.
const { ActivityHandler } = require('botbuilder');

class MyBot extends ActivityHandler {
    // ...
}

// Instantiate a new bot instance.
const bot = new MyBot(conversationState, dialog);
```

That's off the official migration doc found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/javascript-migration-quickreference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)